# text input value greater than.. jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress and trying to throw a message when the value for a text input is greater than 40..

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo wpsc_cart_item_quantity(); ?>" />
```

Now i want to throw a message (alert) when this text field contains value greater than 40 and also want to reset its value to ''
My wordpress theme uses jquery 1.71
I am doing the following:

```
jQuery("input[type='text'][name='quantity']").change(function() {
if (this.val >= 41) {
    alert("To order quantity greater than 40 please use the contact form.");
    this.val == '';
    this.focus();
    return false;
}
});
```

Thanks.​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need in first place to wrap `this` with the `$` function, since this is the DOM element returned by the selection query and not a jQuery object, and the `val()` function is not available on that kind of object.

Also, you need to call the `val()` function with parenthesis, otherwise you're working on the body of the function, not the value it returns.

Finally, there is a typo on the assignment statement. You should at least do `this.val = ''`, but that won't work since `val` is a function, not a variable. Working code should look like this:

```
$("input[type='text'][name='quantity']").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() >= 41) {
        alert("To order quantity greater than 40 please use the contact form.");
        $(this).val('');
        $(this).focus();
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano for the great explanation. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you were nearly there, use:

```
jQuery("input[type='text'][name='quantity']").change(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).val(),10) > 40) {
        alert("To order quantity greater than 40 please use the contact form.");
        this.value == '';
        /* or with jQuery: $(this).val(''); */
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

References:

- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Better `$(this).val('');` instead of `this.val == '';` ?

Comment: Yep! I hadn't looked properly inside of the `if` parentheses when I posted, was editing just after I posted the answer... =/

Comment: Thanks David..Works Perfect..also the parseInt() is useful.